# Declare an array based on a non-constant variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc

```
void foo (int k)
{

int C[size(k)][size(k)];

C[1][2] = 4;

std::cout << C[1][2];

}
```

How this code is compiled correctly?

Comment: You cannot do this with standard c++ as a raw array. Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: But it is compiled on g++ correctly.

Comment: GCC has an extensiion to support VLA's (variable length arrays).

Comment: size() just return k*2.

Comment: @DavidTsaturyan I'll ask it differently.  Where do you get size() from?  There  is no such function in standard C++.

Comment: It isn't standard function.

Comment: @DavidTsaturyan Is your question why this actually compiles with g++?

Comment: Yes, my question about that

Comment: Then you already have the answer: this is a non-standard gcc extension to the C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

You code compiles with g++ because it supports variable length arrays as an extension; see [6.19 Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

It's not a feature of standard C++, so it won't necessarily work with other compilers.

If you want g++ to complain about this sort of thing, give it `-pedantic`.

Comment: Thank you, for clear answer.